# Twitter+Oauth on iPhone: How do you logout?

Tags: iphone

I'm using http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/master for Twitter+Oauth in my iPhone app. I'm trying to create a facebook connect like feature where can log in and log out of twitter. This paticular Twitter+Oauth implementation doesn't use sessions, so I'm not sure how this works.

Does anyone have experience with this and if so how would I go about logging out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to simulate a logout with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)logoutOfTwitter:(id)sender {
    [oauthEngine release];
    oauthEngine = nil;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey: @"authData"];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to clear cookie of Browser Bcz _engine store username and password in cookies.

Here is the right Code for LogOut in Twitter.

```
-(IBAction) onLogOutClick:(id)sender 
{


[_engine clearAccessToken];
[_engine clearsCookies];
[_engine setClearsCookies:YES];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"authData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"authName"];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authName"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authData"]);

[_engine release];
_engine=nil;   

NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"twitter"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much @Justin Gallagher!

I've been looking everywhere for the answer to this and actually saw your answer a while ago, but didn't think there was anything in there I hadn't tried.

I threw every suggestion at it, and the final answer seems to be a combination of yours and the one here: [github_bengottlieb_Twitter-OAuth-iPhone_issues_41](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/issues/41)

What I wasn't doing already (that you suggested) was:

```
oauthEngine = nil;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey: @"authData"];
```

Or in my case:

```
_engine = nil;
```

This causes the twitter view controller to popup again, but without the username & password prompts - therefore just allow and deny buttons.

If you want it to log out altogether and therefore prompt the user for new credentials the next time (without restarting the app), you need to set:

```
_clearsCookies = YES;
```

In the MGTwitterEngine class.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Doing logout, you need to take care of several things like

1. clear the cookies,
2. clear Access Token
3. also remove the objects from
   NSUserDefaults
4. at last release the object.

Otherwise that will create trouble & even the app would get crash when you will try to relogin & it might store your access token. One would be not able to login with new username & password.So this is the mandatory part which one need to take care of it when you are making logout.

```
- (IBAction)logoutOfTwitter:(id)sender
    {
        [_engine clearAccessToken];
        [_engine clearsCookies];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"authData"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"authName"];

        NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authName"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authData"]);

            [_engine release];
             _engine=nil;   
    }
```

Hope now it will be very much clear.Try with it.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
[oauthEngine clearAccessToken];
```

Comment: Does this clear the user login? If so, this is a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

-(IBAction) logoutTwitter:(id)sender
{

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"authData"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"authName"];

_engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
_engine.consumerKey = @"consumerKey";
_engine.consumerSecret = @"consumerSecret";

[_engine clearAccessToken];
//[_engine clearsCookies];
[_engine release];
_engine = nil;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey: @"authData"];

NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"twitter"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}


[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

This code will sign out twitter successfully.